# Ramdisk speeds on older server bottlenecked when rsyncing files vs dd

Tags: linux, performance, raid, rsync

***Why am I seeing poor copy performance in memory?***

**Background and details:**
While testing a RAID 10 on an older server, I wanted to see whether or not other parts of my system were bottlenecking my performance benchmarks. However I noticed something odd after playing with ramdisks:

1. When I dd /dev/zero to a file on the ramdisk (bs=1M), I see 2.4GB/s 
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ramdisk/zero bs=1M count=1000
2. When I rsync --progress the same zero file to a copied file on the same ramdisk, I see ~360MB/s. 
   rsync --progress zero zero2

/dev/urandom performs the same as copying the file across. Copying a debiandvd1.iso performs the same as copying the zero'd file across too. Oddly enough, running the rsync command to copy a file ***to and from*** my RAID 10 array is not far off (~320MB/s - 360MB/s).

Here's exactly how I built the ramdisk:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/create-ramdisk-linux

System is a DL360 G6 and DL380 G6 both running Debian 10 (same test results on both, each have dual Xeon X5550, 1066MHz memory, and an HP Smart Array P410i built in controller).

Comment: What is your question?  These are 2 different beasts.  Rsync is designed to minimize _network_ use by compressing and comparing.  Not optimized for disk read/writes.

Comment: Sorry. my question is why I'm only seeing 360MB/s on RAM copy when I can clearly achieve a maximum of 2.4GB/s. It seems like copying anything other than zeros is highly inefficient compared to what I was anticipating. Maybe the question should be how I can improve that throughput on ram by eliminating a bottleneck (is it software? is it hardware?) Thanks Brian.